# Преобразовать вложенный словарь в dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Имеются след. исходные данные , которые нужно преобразовать в dataframe :

```
[{'id': 11029,
  'name': 'Ростовская область',
  'parent': {'id': 26,
             'name': 'Южный федеральный округ',
             'parent': {'id': 225, 'name': 'Россия', 'type': 'COUNTRY'},
             'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
  'type': 'REPUBLIC'}]
[{'id': 11162,
  'name': 'Свердловская область',
  'parent': {'id': 52,
             'name': 'Уральский федеральный округ',
             'parent': {'id': 225, 'name': 'Россия', 'type': 'COUNTRY'},
             'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
  'type': 'REPUBLIC'}]
[{'id': 11179,
  'name': 'Белоярский',
  'parent': {'id': 99994,
             'name': 'Белоярский район',
             'parent': {'id': 11193,
                        'name': 'Ханты-Мансийский автономный округ - Югра',
                        'parent': {'id': 52,
                                   'name': 'Уральский федеральный округ',
                                   'parent': {'id': 225,
                                              'name': 'Россия',
                                              'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                                   'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                        'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
             'type': 'REPUBLIC_AREA'},
  'type': 'CITY'},
 {'id': 20579,
  'name': 'Белоярский',
  'parent': {'id': 99947,
             'name': 'Белоярский городской округ',
             'parent': {'id': 11162,
                        'name': 'Свердловская область',
                        'parent': {'id': 52,
                                   'name': 'Уральский федеральный округ',
                                   'parent': {'id': 225,
                                              'name': 'Россия',
                                              'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                                   'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                        'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
             'type': 'REPUBLIC_AREA'},
  'type': 'VILLAGE'},
 {'id': 138476,
  'name': 'Белоярский',
  'parent': {'id': 173541,
             'name': 'Белоярское сельское поселение',
             'parent': {'id': 99833,
                        'name': 'Новобурасский район',
                        'parent': {'id': 11146,
                                   'name': 'Саратовская область',
                                   'parent': {'id': 40,
                                              'name': 'Приволжский федеральный '
                                                      'округ',
                                              'parent': {'id': 225,
                                                         'name': 'Россия',
                                                         'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                                              'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                                   'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
                        'type': 'REPUBLIC_AREA'},
             'type': 'OTHER'},
  'type': 'VILLAGE'}]
[{'id': 20282,
  'name': 'Выборгский район',
  'parent': {'id': 2,
             'name': 'Санкт-Петербург',
             'parent': {'id': 10174,
                        'name': 'Санкт-Петербург и Ленинградская область',
                        'parent': {'id': 17,
                                   'name': 'Северо-Западный федеральный округ',
                                   'parent': {'id': 225,
                                              'name': 'Россия',
                                              'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                                   'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                        'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
             'type': 'CITY'},
  'type': 'CITY_DISTRICT'},
 {'id': 98622,
  'name': 'Выборгский район',
  'parent': {'id': 10174,
             'name': 'Санкт-Петербург и Ленинградская область',
             'parent': {'id': 17,
                        'name': 'Северо-Западный федеральный округ',
                        'parent': {'id': 225,
                                   'name': 'Россия',
                                   'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                        'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
             'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
  'type': 'REPUBLIC_AREA'}]
```

Как получить на выходе примерно такую таблицу?

| id | name | type | p1_id | p1_name | p2_id | p2_name | p3_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11029 | Ростовская область | REPUBLIC | 26 | ЮФО | 225 | Россия | NaN |

думаю принцип понятен

Comment: вы можете хотя бы часть исходных данных выложить в воспроизводимом виде?

Comment: А что вы потом с этим будете делать? Я к тому, что может вам не такое вообще нужно преобразование. В таком виде мне кажется дальше будет не очень удобно с этим работать.

Comment: @strawdog выложил часть исходных

Comment: @CrazyElf Вы правы, поправил желаемый пример

Comment: просто перевести ваши данные в датафрейм со вложенными словарем - не проблема. проблема в том, что дальше делать со значениями. которые являются словарями неизвестного и разного уровня вложенности - мало того, что это проблематично реализовать, так и работать потом с этими данными будет очень непросто.

Comment: @ВикторСмольский Не факт, что и в таком виде это будет удобно. Вы скажите - что и как вы потом с этим делать планируете? Не лучше ли табличный вид сохранить со статическим числом колонок, из которого проще делать выборки. Ну то есть в такие же колонки просто развернуть эти данные, например. Возможно, добавив колонку `parent_id`, или ещё как-то так. Всё зависит от дальнейшего сценария использования.

Comment: @strawdog в данных максимум 5 уровней вложенности

Comment: @CrazyElf просто требуется полный справочник регионов для соединения двух табличек ( logs api метрики и директа) .  Число колонок должно быть статическое, я неточно нарисовал таблицу. Развернуть вложенные данные в такие же колонки вполне подходящий вариант

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось так, собрав исходные данные в список:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[{'id': 11029,
         'name': 'Ростовская область',
         'parent': {'id': 26,
                    'name': 'Южный федеральный округ',
                    'parent': {'id': 225, 'name': 'Россия', 'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                    'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
         'type': 'REPUBLIC'}],
       [{'id': 11162,
         'name': 'Свердловская область',
         'parent': {'id': 52,
                    'name': 'Уральский федеральный округ',
                    'parent': {'id': 225, 'name': 'Россия', 'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                    'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
         'type': 'REPUBLIC'}],
       [{'id': 11179,
         'name': 'Белоярский',
         'parent': {'id': 99994,
                    'name': 'Белоярский район',
                    'parent': {'id': 11193,
                               'name': 'Ханты-Мансийский автономный округ - Югра',
                               'parent': {'id': 52,
                                          'name': 'Уральский федеральный округ',
                                          'parent': {'id': 225,
                                                     'name': 'Россия',
                                                     'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                                          'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                               'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
                    'type': 'REPUBLIC_AREA'},
         'type': 'CITY'},
        {'id': 20579,
         'name': 'Белоярский',
         'parent': {'id': 99947,
                    'name': 'Белоярский городской округ',
                    'parent': {'id': 11162,
                               'name': 'Свердловская область',
                               'parent': {'id': 52,
                                          'name': 'Уральский федеральный округ',
                                          'parent': {'id': 225,
                                                     'name': 'Россия',
                                                     'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                                          'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                               'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
                    'type': 'REPUBLIC_AREA'},
         'type': 'VILLAGE'},
        {'id': 138476,
         'name': 'Белоярский',
         'parent': {'id': 173541,
                    'name': 'Белоярское сельское поселение',
                    'parent': {'id': 99833,
                               'name': 'Новобурасский район',
                               'parent': {'id': 11146,
                                          'name': 'Саратовская область',
                                          'parent': {'id': 40,
                                                     'name': 'Приволжский федеральный '
                                                             'округ',
                                                     'parent': {'id': 225,
                                                                'name': 'Россия',
                                                                'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                                                     'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                                          'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
                               'type': 'REPUBLIC_AREA'},
                    'type': 'OTHER'},
         'type': 'VILLAGE'}],
       [{'id': 20282,
         'name': 'Выборгский район',
         'parent': {'id': 2,
                    'name': 'Санкт-Петербург',
                    'parent': {'id': 10174,
                               'name': 'Санкт-Петербург и Ленинградская область',
                               'parent': {'id': 17,
                                          'name': 'Северо-Западный федеральный округ',
                                          'parent': {'id': 225,
                                                     'name': 'Россия',
                                                     'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                                          'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                               'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
                    'type': 'CITY'},
         'type': 'CITY_DISTRICT'},
        {'id': 98622,
         'name': 'Выборгский район',
         'parent': {'id': 10174,
                    'name': 'Санкт-Петербург и Ленинградская область',
                    'parent': {'id': 17,
                               'name': 'Северо-Западный федеральный округ',
                               'parent': {'id': 225,
                                          'name': 'Россия',
                                          'type': 'COUNTRY'},
                               'type': 'COUNTRY_DISTRICT'},
                    'type': 'REPUBLIC'},
         'type': 'REPUBLIC_AREA'}]]

ser = pd.Series(data=lst)
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame()
# Преобразуем столбец в датафрейм с нужными столбцами
for i in range(ser.size):
    df_tmp = pd.concat([df_tmp, pd.DataFrame.from_records(ser[i],
                                columns=['id', 'name', 'type', 'parent'])], ignore_index=True)

df = df_tmp[['id', 'name', 'type']].copy()
# запоминаем индексы не пустых строк
not_null = df_tmp[df_tmp['parent'].notna()].index
i = 1
# в цикле добавляем следующие столбцы пока 'parent' не пустой
while not not_null.empty:
# Убираем закончившиеся строки из дальнейшего расширения таблицы
    df_tmp = df_tmp.dropna()
# Для работы from_records нужно сбрасывать индексы строк уже дошедшими до конца по "nan"
    df_tmp = df_tmp.reset_index()
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_tmp['parent'], columns=['id', 'name', 'type', 'parent'])
# Возвращаем индексы оставшихся неразобранных строк для добавления в нужное место
    df_tmp = df_tmp.set_index(not_null)
    df = df.join(df_tmp[['id', 'name', 'type']], rsuffix=f'_{i}')
# запоминаем индексы еще не пустых строк
    not_null = df_tmp[df_tmp['parent'].notna()].index
    i += 1
```

```
          id                  name           type  ...   id_5  name_5   type_5
0   11029    Ростовская область       REPUBLIC  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN
1   11162  Свердловская область       REPUBLIC  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN
2   11179            Белоярский           CITY  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN
3   20579            Белоярский        VILLAGE  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN
4  138476            Белоярский        VILLAGE  ...  225.0  Россия  COUNTRY
5   20282      Выборгский район  CITY_DISTRICT  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN
6   98622      Выборгский район  REPUBLIC_AREA  ...    NaN     NaN      NaN

[7 rows x 18 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Более правильное решение задачи - так как данные объекты почти JSON:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for adds in lst:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(adds)], ignore_index=True)
```